# How to Print LibreOffice Calc Document on A2 or Larger Paper When Default Settings Limit to A4?

Tags: printing, libreoffice-calc

this is my first question on the platform, long time fan, first time participating.

I am currently working with LibreOffice Calc and have encountered an issue with printing documents. I need to print a spreadsheet on A2 paper size (or larger), but the default print dialog in LibreOffice Calc restricts me to selecting no larger than A4. I've searched through the LibreOffice documentation and forums for a solution but haven't found a clear process to achieve this.

**My Questions:**

1. Is there a direct way to enable A2 (or larger) paper sizes in LibreOffice Calc's print dialog that I might have overlooked? [checked all the help](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/scalc/guide/print_details.html?&DbPAR=CALC&System=UNIX)
2. If not, are there recommended workarounds or settings adjustments in LibreOffice Calc to prepare a document for printing on larger paper sizes effectively?
3. For the PDF export method, are there specific settings or steps to ensure the document scales correctly and maintains high quality when printed on A2 paper?

**Environment:**

- LibreOffice Version: [7.6.4.1 X86_64]
- Operating System: [Kubuntu - Linux]

I would greatly appreciate any guidance, tips, or solutions that could help me prepare a PDF document ready to print A2 or larger paper sizes effectively. Thank you in advance for your assistance!

**What I've tried:**

1. **Exporting to PDF:** Considering a workaround, I exported the document to PDF to print from a PDF viewer, hoping it would allow scaling or selecting A2 as the print size. It did not.
2. **Printer Settings:** I checked my printer settings, but this is irrelevant since I will print this at a local shop ... also my printer is accepts A4 maximum.
3. **from SuperUser.com** this [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/30955/how-do-i-print-a-large-page-on-multiple-smaller-pages) is to cumbersome, I really think LibreOffice is capable of doing this, I just don't know how...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I got the answer from @VeRo
I am curious though, and will give this a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What a coincidence !

I literally just solved this very issue for a poster I am trying to print. You were really close in your research, I found the answer in the LibreOffice Help.

Here is my **`.ODF`** document with the default A4 print helper lines:

[image]

You can see how the dashed lines are cutting through the table.
By going to **`Format > PageS Style`**  you get this dialog:

[image]

By selecting `User` and setting `width: 594mm`  and `height: 420mm` then hitting `OK` you get the exact boundary you are looking for, the ISO standard A2  ( **width** x **height** ).
I also recommend unchecking the `header` and `footer` options.

Now all you need to do is **`Export Directly as PDF`**

[image]

And then this is the output:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: As I said, it was coincidental, but you are welcome !